# System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll causing issues with Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json.net

My Windows service is in the same solution as a MVC project.

The MVC project uses a reference to SignalR Client which requires Newtonsoft.Json v6 +

the Windows service uses System.Net.Http.Formatting, which requires Newtonsoft.Json version 4.5.0.0.

I assumed this would not be a problem, as I could just use a binding redirect in my App.Config, however I get an error of

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred
>   in System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

my app.config has the following:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

I added that myself, and it does not work, I have also tried uninstalling and re-installing Json.Net with the nuget package manager, to no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the assemblyBinding tag have proper xmlns schema? Check if the issue you are encountering is same as [Assembly binding redirect does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490327/assembly-binding-redirect-does-not-work)

Comment: i have no xmlns written on the assembly binding as it should work without it

nevermind, that worked. You saved me hours, thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

We faced same error and struggled to fix for few days. We finally we found this post on stack overflow [Assembly reference cannot be resolved - dependentAssembly issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21876887/assembly-reference-cannot-be-resolved-dependentassembly-issue/22611079#22611079)

This made us realize to look into the version of `System.Net.Http.Formatting` being used and we found that our solution had been using multiple version of `System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll` and those each of them were referencing different version of `Newtonsoft.Json.dll`.

Removing references of older version of `System.Net.Http.Formatting` and adding references back, fixed the problem.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I had to remove the NuGet package, along with a package that it depended upon, delete the Newtonsoft DLL from my web site's Bin directory, and remove the assembly info from the bottom of web.config. Then I installed the _depending_ NuGet package, which pulled in its favorite version of Newtonsoft. Then everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

@chintan123 actually pointed my in the right direction, turns out that despite the class library I was creating had a reference to both `System.Net.Http.Formatting` and also `Newtonsoft.Json`, only the former was being copied to the `bin` directory of the calling project that needed it.

Adding a reference to `Newtonsoft.Json` to the main calling project fixed the issue.